# Reading part of the line in CSV file in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read the csv file which has the data like this :

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

My1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70

My2,10,20,30,40,50,60

My3,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Now I want to store the My,My1.... in `@names` and the numbers in each row to `@numbers`.

Till now I have made this code

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Text::CSV;

  my $file = "result.csv";
  my @names = undef;
  my @numbers = undef;
  open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";

  my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({
      binary    => 1,
      auto_diag => 1,
      });
    shift(@names);
    shift(@numbers);
  while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    push(@names,$row->[0]);
    push(@numbers,$row->[1...5]);
      }
  close $fh;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#names ) {
    print "names:$names[$i] \tNumbers:$numbers[$i] \n";
}
```

But this code is not working and just if I use `@numbers` while printing then its printing the all numbers in front of all names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand the question, but here there's the possible solution:

Reading:

```
...
my @names = ();
my @numbers = ();

open CSVFILE, 'result.csv';
my $j = 0;
while (my $line = <CSVFILE>) {
  chomp;
  my @csv_line = split(/\s?,\s?/, $line);
  push @names, $csv_line[0]; #or $names[$j] = $csv_line[0];
  for (my $i = 1; $i <= $#csv_line; $i++) {
    $numbers[$j][$i] = $csv_line[$i]; # $i-th number, for the $j-name
  }
  $j++;
}
close(CSVFILE);
```

Writing:

```
...
my $name;
my @numbers;
my $new_line = join(',', ($name, @numbers));
open CSVFILE, '>>result.csv';
print CSVFILE "$new_line\n";
close CSVFILE;
```

Printing:

```
...
my $M = $names;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $M; $i++) {
  print $names[$i] . ":\n ";
  my $N = $numbers[$i];
  for (my $k = 0; $k < $N; $k++) {
    print $numbers[$i][$k] . " ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
...
```

prints:

```
My1:
 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 
My2:
 10 20 30 40 50 60 
My3:
 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80
```

Comment: Thankyou for the help but I am confused at one point that when I print the number values then it's giving Names:array (0x105cb4329)

Comment: One of the correct ways to print it is with two nested for:
`...
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#names; $i++) {
print "name: " . $names[$i] . "\n";
  my $N = $numbers[$i];
  for (my $k = 0; $k <= $N; $k++) {
    print $numbers[$i][$k] . " ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
...`

Comment: I don't know why but your code gives error while reading the CSV file using While option 
Error: Syntax error near while my

Comment: it is `while (my $line = <CSVFILE>)` and not `while $line (...` i apologized.

Answer (score 1):

Problems like this are often easier to solve if you give some thought to the most appropriate data structure to use. Storing linked data across two different variables (like your `@names` and `@numbers`) is rarely a good idea.

I've stored the data in a hash. The keys are your names and the values are references to arrays storing your numbers.

(Oh, and to simplify the example I've switched to storing the data in the source file.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Text::CSV;

my %data;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({
  binary    => 1,
  auto_diag => 1,
});

while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA)) {
  # First element in @$row is the name, which we use as the key.
  # Rest of @$row contains the numbers.
  $data{shift @$row} = $row;
}

foreach (sort keys %data) {
  say "$_: @{$data{$_}}";
}

__END__
My1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70
My2,10,20,30,40,50,60
My3,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80
```